# how to call javascript function from managed bean?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have if condition in managed bean. I want to display alert when condition is true. How I do that? something like:

```
    public void catInsert()
        {
            if(abr.searchCategoryByCategoryName(CategoryName)!=null){
    //                msg = "<div style = 'color:red'>CategoryName already exist!</div>";
    //                System.out.println(msg);
//  i want alert here

            }else
            {
            abr.addCategory(CategoryName);
            CategoryName="";
            }
         }
```

and xhtml page is;

```
<table class="nostyle">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                    <h:outputText value="Category Name:"></h:outputText>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputText id="txtcatname" value="#{categoryBean.categoryName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter category Name" >
                        </h:inputText>
                    </td>
                    <td ><h:message for="txtcatname" style="color: #df0000"></h:message></td>>            
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <h:commandButton id="submit" type="Submit" value="submit" action="#{categoryBean.catInsert()}" >
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: What's the problem with that? Where is your actual condition ?

Comment: The client has to keep talking to the bean to find out

Comment: I have updated question.Please give me solution

Answer (score 2):

You're making a conceptual mistake. HTML/JS code doesn't belong in the controller, but in the view. The controller has to inform the view somehow that it has to generate the desired bunch of HTML/JS code.

You could do that by setting a boolean property like so

```
private boolean showCategoryNameAlert;

public void catInsert() {
    if (abr.searchCategoryByCategoryName(categoryName) != null) {
        showCategoryNameAlert = true;
    } else {
        abr.addCategory(categoryName);
    }
}

public boolean isShowCategoryNameAlert() {
    return showCategoryNameAlert;
}
```

with

```html
<h:outputScript rendered="#{categoryBean.showCategoryNameAlert}">
    alert("CategoryName already exist!");
</h:outputScript>
```

By the way, why don't you use `FacesContext#addMessage()` with `<h:messages>` or maybe even a normal JSF `Validator` on the input field? Showing JavaScript alerts is soo 90's and performing input validation in an action method is poor design.